# Pipes in flappy bird clone stop drawing whenever I try to make them move

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have revised my code and have a start on the pipes, it draws them then it is supposed to move them but whenever I uncomment my code that is supposed to make the pipes move it stops drawing the pipes, Would anyone be able to help me out?

This is the code I have for the pipes so far:

```
function piper() {
    let pipex = 600
    fill(34, 139, 34)
    noStroke()
    rect(pipex, 0, 30, 50)
    rect(pipex, 80, 30, 600)

    for (i = 0; i < 600; i += 1) {
        pipex--
    };
};
```

here is the entire game code

```js
    let y;
    let vel;
    let onoff = 1;
    let gravity = 0.6;
    let lift = -10;
    let pipes = [];
    let x, height;

    function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    piped()
    y = 300;
    vel = 0;
    }

    function piped() {
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i += 1) {
        pipes.push({
            x: 600,
            height: random(10, 550)
        })
    }
    }

    function draw() {
    background(100, 100, 255);

    vel += gravity;
    y += vel;
    let eye = y - 10;

    fall();
    piper();

    stroke('rgba(220,20,60.60)');
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    ellipse(200, y, 25, 25);

    };

    function endGame() {
    onoff - 1
    }

    if (onoff === 1) {
    function keyPressed() {
        if (keyCode === 32) {
            vel = lift;
        };
    };

    function fall() {
        if (y >= height - 25) {
            y = height - 25;
            endGame();
        } else if (y <= 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y >= 590) {
            y = 590
        }
    };

    function piper() {
        let pipex = 600
        fill(34, 139, 34)
        noStroke()
        rect(pipex, 0, 30, 50)
        rect(pipex, 80, 30, 600)

        for (i = 0; i < 600; i += 1) {
            pipex--
        };
    };

    } else if (onoff === 0) {
    function draw() {
        background(255, 0, 0)
    }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add enough code so that we can see what it is doing?

Comment: I added the entire code it just needs some HTML code to run thru chrome

Comment: in the piper function there are two calls to draw rectangles. They both draw a rectangle with x position of 600. Since the canvas is 600 by 600 both of these will be off the canvas. Is this what you intend? Also take a look at the for loop at the bottom of piper. The for loop decrements pipex but nothing uses pipex after it is decremented.. if you are wanting to move the pipes you can declare pipex outside of the function.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that error. Also, thank you for the movement help!